# What does 'name__iexact' mean in django model filters?

Tags: django, filter

`name_iexact` keyword is a parameter we can pass to filter function in django.model. Can someone please help me understand what it does?

```
Map.objects.filter(name__iexact=self.cleaned_data["name"]).count()
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a case insensitive match. It will retrive database records with "name" field matching `self.cleaned_data["name"]`, while the case doesn't necessarily have to match.

You can construct those lookups appending `__iexact` to any field name. See the documentation for [more on iexact](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact) or for list of [other similar field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are using Django or some kind of ORM.

*name__iexact* means that you are doing a case insensitive match on the field *name*

check for instance http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/ for more documentation on django queries.

I hope this will help you,
Jerome Wagner